# How do I select a div based on $(this) selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code looks something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 "use strict";
 $(".box_button").click(function(){
  var content_front = $(this).closest('.front');
  var content_back = $(this).parents('.box_content');
  
  content_front.addClass("flip_1"); 
  content_back.addClass("flip_2");
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f4f4f4;  
}

.col_x4 {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 7px; 
}

.box {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 4px;
 perspective: 1000px;
}

.box_top {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 border-bottom: hidden;
}

.box_top img {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.box_top img:hover {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}

.box_content {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
 transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 min-height: 281px;
}

.back {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: #fff;
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 min-height: 281px;
}

.flip_1 {
 z-index: 1;
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip_2 {
 z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(360deg);
 backface-visibility: visible;
}

.box_title {
 position: relative;
 margin: 10px 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center; 
}

.t1::after,
.t2::after {
 content: "";
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 margin: 10px 0 0;
 background: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/05/07/02/47/green-47700_960_720.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.t2::before {
 content: "";
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 90px;
 background: url(../images/basket-full.png) no-repeat center center;
 background-size: contain;
 margin: 25px 0 5px;
}

.box_description {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 5% 15px;
 padding: 0 15px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 20px;
 max-height: 100px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.box_description::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  width: 4px;  /* for vertical scrollbars */
  height: 4px; /* for horizontal scrollbars */
}

.box_description::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
  background: #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.box_description::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
  background: rgba(61,82,95,0.3);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.box_price {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 5% 15px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 600; 
}

.box_button {
 z-index: 3;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 70%;
 height: 36px;
 margin: 0 auto 15px;
 line-height: 36px;
 color: #333;
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-radius: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_1 {
 border-color: #008CFF;
}

.btn_2 {
 border-color: #F89A00;
}

.btn_active {
 z-index: 4;
 -webkit-animation: scale_up 0.6s linear;
 animation: scale_up 0.6s linear; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale_up {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  transform: scale(1,1);
  }
  50% {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
  }
  100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}

@keyframes scale_up {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  transform: scale(1,1);
  }
  50% {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
  }
  100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col_x4">
 <div class="box">
     <div class="box_top">
         <img src="http://oregonaitc.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/potato.jpg" alt="product" />
        </div>
        <div class="box_content">
         <div class="front">
             <h2 class="box_title t1">Title</h2>
                <p class="box_description">Description</p>
                <div class="box_price">$10</div>
                <a class="box_button btn_1">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
             <h2 class="box_title t2">Flip side title</h2>
                <p class="box_description">Product added to basket.</p>
                <a class="box_button btn_1">Pay</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I select div "back" based on the click of the button using $(this) selector assigned to the box? I don't want to use unique ID's or classes to specify exactly which button in which box is being clicked.

I used the .closest method to select div "front". How do I do the same for div "back"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the main container first and work from there:

```
$(".box_button").click(function(){
    var $box = $(this).parents('.box');
    var content_front = $box.find('.front');
    var content_back = $box.find('.back');

    content_front.addClass("flip_1");   
    content_back.addClass("flip_2");
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 "use strict";
 $(".box_button").click(function(){
        var $box = $(this).parents('.box');
  var content_front = $box.find('.front');
  var content_back = $box.find('.back');
  
  content_front.addClass("flip_1"); 
  content_back.addClass("flip_2");
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f4f4f4;  
}

.col_x4 {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 7px; 
}

.box {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 4px;
 perspective: 1000px;
}

.box_top {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 border-bottom: hidden;
}

.box_top img {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.box_top img:hover {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}

.box_content {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
 transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 min-height: 281px;
}

.back {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: #fff;
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 min-height: 281px;
}

.flip_1 {
 z-index: 1;
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip_2 {
 z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(360deg);
 backface-visibility: visible;
}

.box_title {
 position: relative;
 margin: 10px 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center; 
}

.t1::after,
.t2::after {
 content: "";
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 margin: 10px 0 0;
 background: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/05/07/02/47/green-47700_960_720.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.t2::before {
 content: "";
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 90px;
 background: url(../images/basket-full.png) no-repeat center center;
 background-size: contain;
 margin: 25px 0 5px;
}

.box_description {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 5% 15px;
 padding: 0 15px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 20px;
 max-height: 100px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.box_description::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  width: 4px;  /* for vertical scrollbars */
  height: 4px; /* for horizontal scrollbars */
}

.box_description::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
  background: #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.box_description::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
  background: rgba(61,82,95,0.3);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.box_price {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 5% 15px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 600; 
}

.box_button {
 z-index: 3;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 70%;
 height: 36px;
 margin: 0 auto 15px;
 line-height: 36px;
 color: #333;
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-radius: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_1 {
 border-color: #008CFF;
}

.btn_2 {
 border-color: #F89A00;
}

.btn_active {
 z-index: 4;
 -webkit-animation: scale_up 0.6s linear;
 animation: scale_up 0.6s linear; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale_up {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  transform: scale(1,1);
  }
  50% {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
  }
  100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}

@keyframes scale_up {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  transform: scale(1,1);
  }
  50% {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px -8px 55px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
  }
  100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col_x4">
 <div class="box">
     <div class="box_top">
         <img src="http://oregonaitc.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/potato.jpg" alt="product" />
        </div>
        <div class="box_content">
         <div class="front">
             <h2 class="box_title t1">Title</h2>
                <p class="box_description">Description</p>
                <div class="box_price">$10</div>
                <a class="box_button btn_1">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
             <h2 class="box_title t2">Flip side title</h2>
                <p class="box_description">Product added to basket.</p>
                <a class="box_button btn_1">Pay</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to traverse up to parent then target immediately following siblings element

```
var content_back = $(this).parent().next('.back');
```

Or

```
var content_back = $(this). closest('.box_content').find('.back')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` on the parent container to look for the back element - see example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
$(".box_button").click(function(){
 var content_front = $(this).closest('.front');
 var content_back = $(this).parents('.box_content');
 
 content_front.addClass("flip_1"); 
 content_back.addClass("flip_2");
    var backContainer = $(this).parent().find('.back');
    console.log('backContainer',backContainer);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col_x4">
 <div class="box">
     <div class="box_top">
         <img src="http://oregonaitc.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/potato.jpg" alt="product" />
        </div>
        <div class="box_content">
         <div class="front">
             <h2 class="box_title t1">Title</h2>
                <p class="box_description">Description</p>
                <div class="box_price">$10</div>
                <a class="box_button btn_1">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
             <h2 class="box_title t2">Flip side title</h2>
                <p class="box_description">Product added to basket.</p>
                <a class="box_button btn_1">Pay</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like:

```
var content_back = $(this).parent().find('.back');
```

This will look for the parent of the `a` node and finds the node with the `back` HTML class.